# Python cycle is not working (xlwt)

Tags: python, excel, cmd, xlwt

I have this piece of code in Python, that should be working.

```
python

import xlwt 

#== change variables according to requirements ==#

numoftopcol = 5

numoftestcases = 4

coltext = ['Test Case', 'Test Name', 'Duration', 'Factual Result', 'Result (Pass/Fail)']

testN = ['void','Get Counter Result', 'Read Stats', 'Client Initialization', 'Start Server']

#== change variables according to requirements ==#

styleH = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Arial, bold on, color-index blue;')

styleH.font.height = 400

stylee = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Arial')

wb = xlwt.Workbook()

ws = wb.add_sheet('Test Case Overview')

c = 0

numoftopcol += 1

for c in range(c,numoftopcol):

     ws.write(0, c, coltext[c], styleH),

     ws.col(c).width = 7000


import random

c = 1

numoftestcases += 1

for c in range(c,numoftestcases):

     strC = str(c),

     ws.write(c,0,'TC-'+strC,stylee),

     ws.write(c,1,testN[c],stylee),

     ws.write(c,2,'DUR',stylee),

     ws.write(c,3,'RandomStr',stylee),

     randomint = random.randint(0,1),

     if randomint == 0:

          ws.write(c,4,'PASS',stylee)

     else:

          ws.write(c,4,'FAIL',stylee)
```

Now, the first cycle is working fine (the one with styleH). The second one is not working (stylee). Debugging I found, that c=1 and numoftestcases=5. So if c < numoftestcases or 1<5, then the cycle should be working, right?

Apparently it does not. I get the following error outputs in the cmd (for the second cycle).

> forTraceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 2, in 
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 3, in 
>   TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

What is wrong with this?
Earlier this worked I remember. I did not change the cycle code but now it isn't working.

I also tried putting a print(c) in the first line in the second cycle and the output was only 1. No more numbers were following.

Checking the xls file, only the first cycle was written in the spreadsheet.

I store this code on a text file so I can recall this command whenever I need to in cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: index out of range: you define `numoftopcol` to 5 which is the `len` of the list, but just before the loop you increment it... Now access to this index yields out of range...

The root cause of the error is that excel coordinates start at 1 but python lists are 0-indexed. I would do loops from `0` to `n` and add 1 only for `xlwt` calls instead of doing all the `+1` stuff you're doing.

Second: concatenation error: you didn't post any stacktrace but

```
strC = str(c),
```

creates a `tuple`. And the next line:

```
 ws.write(c,0,'TC-'+strC,stylee),
```

tries to add a `str` to a `tuple`.

Comment: I can see that but how do I fix this? The numoftopcol isn't causing the problem but numoftestcases does.

Comment: `numoftopcol` is out of range and skipping first element. Post stacktrace if you want a better diagnostic

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue. I had to convert the data types of `c` and `numoftestcases` to int.

```
int(c)
int(numoftestcases)
```

Case solved. It's working now.